# React Native IOS simulator Debug menu not opening

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

This is my first time using react native IOS. I was trying to run my application in ios simulator. But the problem is I need to set debug server host & port for device in dev settings. cmd + d tried but no response debug menu is not opening struck here if anyone has a fix please post here. Its a blocker could not move forward. I am not using useFrameworks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you are on simulator tab go to I/O menu -> keyboard and check "use hardware keyboard".

This should do the job.

[simulator I/O tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCqhA.png)

Comment: I tried this even though it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Felix's answer solved my problem, but there are a couple of other things to try.

You can press "d" in the Metro terminal console and it will send a signal to open the menu remotely. (However this doesn't always work either). You'll see:

```
info Opening developer menu...
```

I have found CMD-r (reload) starts recording the screenshot in the simulator as that key is already bound, so I experimented and found just pressing "r" works for reload. Then I found just pressing "d" in the focused simulator opens the debug menu.